# CS1513 } expected error on Linqpad whilst using a while loop with embedded if statements (c# in Linqpad)

Tags: c#, linqpad, object-expected

I'm a student and quite new to c# and linqpad. I'm writing a basic text based game using c# statement(s). For some reason, the CS1513 } expected error keeps popping up but I have checked and I am not missing any brackets. I have seen another question asking almost the same as me and they received an answer however it did not help me in my case. Here is my code:

```
 Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Now, your father left some unfinished work through no fault of his own.");
    Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Due to the execution of Romonav, the common people are not very happy");
    Console.WriteLine(name + ": Whose Romonav?");
    Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Lets just say that he was a bit too eager to speak his troubled mind.");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Now, there are three options on how to deal with the rioting scum");
    while (true)
    {
        bool reply = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: You can either wipe them out, meet their demands (fair elections and for you to step down) or you can ignore them");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: So which one will it be, my Beloved Oppressor?");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        //1st choice 



        if (answer == "wipe them out")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Very well my glorious leader, I will mobilise the troops");
            Console.WriteLine("-1 for people, -1 for UN and +1 for Higher Class");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Due to the previous decision, UN has called you out for 'inhumane' killings.");
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: However, they are yet to take action");
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: You can either ignore them, threaten them or apologise in public");
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Which will it be?");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
            //2nd choice a
            if (answer == "apologise in public")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Nice choice, my Unmerciful Leader, I will organise a speech for you");
                Console.WriteLine("+1 for people, +1 for UN and -1 for Higher Class");//0 for people, 0 for UN and 0 for higher class
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Exellent speech my ruler, unfortunately there seems to be a new vigilante group who does accept your apology");
                Console.WriteLine(name + ": Who are they?");
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: They call themselves NELANZKILE, it's Zulu for 'The Clean'");
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Last week they assasinated a number of our officers");
                Console.WriteLine(name + ": Hmpf... Then like the Zulu, they shall be crushed");
            }
            //2nd choice a 
            if (answer == "threaten them")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Good idea Supreme Ruler, maybe they won't dare to take action");
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: I will release the video of the beheading of agent Stoker to the UN");
                Console.WriteLine("/ for people, -2 for UN and +1 for higher class"); //-3 for UN, -1 for ppl and +2 for higher class
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            //2nd choice a
            if (answer1 == "ignore them")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Very well, I will tell the officers to carry on as normal");
                Console.WriteLine("/ for people, / for UN and -1 for Higher Class"); //-1 for ppl, -1 for UN and 0 for Higher Class
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }


        }


        if (answer == "meet their demands")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Good idea my Omnipotent Victor, perhaps you will be re-elected because of this");
            Console.WriteLine("+2 for people, +1 for UN and -2 for Higher Class");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": Skarvich? My friend, what are you doing here with that gun?");
            Console.WriteLine("Skarvich: Forgive me Supreme Leader, but you have doomed us all with your weak will...");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine("YOU HAVE BEEN ASSASINATED BY A HIGHER CLASS FRIEND DUE TO YOUR INABILITY TO STAY DICTATOR");

        }
        break;
    }
        else {
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: I do not think that decision will work");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: You can either wipe them out, meet their demands (fair elections and for you to step down) or you can ignore them");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: So which one will it be, my Beloved Oppressor?");
    }
```

Comment: The last `else` clause appears to be hanging. Please check and correct.

Comment: @shahkalpesh thanks, I have edited it

Comment: I dont see any edits. If you paste the code above in linqpad, it shows error on `}` before the last else block.

Comment: The closure of the while block is followed by an _else {.... }_ but there is no if matching that else. Probably you want that else inside the while block

Comment: @shahkalpesh exactly, that's what I'm having trouble with

Comment: @Steve I was under the impression that you just needed a while clause to match with an else clause

Comment: No, else follow an if not while or for

Comment: Also check your use of the variables _answer_ and _answer1_ In the first if you should use _answer1_ to test for the subconditions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `while` loop followed by an `else` block.

This compiles, although there are still plenty of non-compilation errors for you to work on.

```
var name = "E. Lee";
Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Now, your father left some unfinished work through no fault of his own.");
Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Due to the execution of Romonav, the common people are not very happy");
Console.WriteLine(name + ": Whose Romonav?");
Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Lets just say that he was a bit too eager to speak his troubled mind.");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
Console.WriteLine(" ");
Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Now, there are three options on how to deal with the rioting scum");
while (true)
{
    bool reply = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Quetin: You can either wipe them out, meet their demands (fair elections and for you to step down) or you can ignore them");
    Console.WriteLine("Quetin: So which one will it be, my Beloved Oppressor?");
    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    //1st choice 



    if (answer == "wipe them out")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Very well my glorious leader, I will mobilise the troops");
        Console.WriteLine("-1 for people, -1 for UN and +1 for Higher Class");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Due to the previous decision, UN has called you out for 'inhumane' killings.");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: However, they are yet to take action");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: You can either ignore them, threaten them or apologise in public");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Which will it be?");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
        //2nd choice a
        if (answer == "apologise in public")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Nice choice, my Unmerciful Leader, I will organise a speech for you");
            Console.WriteLine("+1 for people, +1 for UN and -1 for Higher Class");//0 for people, 0 for UN and 0 for higher class
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Exellent speech my ruler, unfortunately there seems to be a new vigilante group who does accept your apology");
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": Who are they?");
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: They call themselves NELANZKILE, it's Zulu for 'The Clean'");
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Last week they assasinated a number of our officers");
            Console.WriteLine(name + ": Hmpf... Then like the Zulu, they shall be crushed");
        }
        //2nd choice a 
        if (answer == "threaten them")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Good idea Supreme Ruler, maybe they won't dare to take action");
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: I will release the video of the beheading of agent Stoker to the UN");
            Console.WriteLine("/ for people, -2 for UN and +1 for higher class"); //-3 for UN, -1 for ppl and +2 for higher class
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
        //2nd choice a
        if (answer1 == "ignore them")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Very well, I will tell the officers to carry on as normal");
            Console.WriteLine("/ for people, / for UN and -1 for Higher Class"); //-1 for ppl, -1 for UN and 0 for Higher Class
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }


    }


    if (answer == "meet their demands")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: Good idea my Omnipotent Victor, perhaps you will be re-elected because of this");
        Console.WriteLine("+2 for people, +1 for UN and -2 for Higher Class");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(name + ": Skarvich? My friend, what are you doing here with that gun?");
        Console.WriteLine("Skarvich: Forgive me Supreme Leader, but you have doomed us all with your weak will...");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("YOU HAVE BEEN ASSASINATED BY A HIGHER CLASS FRIEND DUE TO YOUR INABILITY TO STAY DICTATOR");

    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: I do not think that decision will work");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: You can either wipe them out, meet their demands (fair elections and for you to step down) or you can ignore them");
        Console.WriteLine("Quetin: So which one will it be, my Beloved Oppressor?");
    }
    break;
}
```